# Map parenthetical substrings from one array to another array and use a fallback string when no parenthetical substring

Tags: php, arrays, regex, mapping, parentheses

After modifying a query result, I end up with an array like the following example:

```
[0] => foo (bar1)
[1] => bar (foo2)
[2] => bas
[3] => foo (bas3)
[4] => bar
```

As you can see, some of the values contain parentheses, some don't.

I need the parentheses part of each value in an own (new) array. The key should be retained. If there are no parentheses in the value of the first array, the value in the second array should be `&nbsp;` instead. The array keys in both arrays should be identical. The second array should therefore look like this:

```
[0] => (bar1)
[1] => (foo2)
[2] => 
[3] => (bas3)
[4] =>
```

Up to now I got this PHP code:

```
$pattern = "/\((.*?)\)/";  //Looks for text in parentheses
$array1 = <see above>
$array2 = array();     //The second array, which should contain the extracted parentheses parts
foreach($array1 as $index => $value) {
  $array2 = preg_grep($pattern,$array1);
}
```

This works fine, but it displays the whole value of `$array1` as value in `$array2`, when parentheses are found. Values in `$array1` without parentheses are missing completely.
I cannot come up with a solution to only extract the (...)-part, remove it from `$array1` and add `&nbsp;` to `$array2` if no parentheses are detected. I tried using preg_match to achieve this, but that gave me an array to string conversion error.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this problem solved?

Comment: You say after modifying a query result - is it possible to change the way that works to make the next step easier?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help

```
$pattern = "/\((.*?)\)/";  
$array1 = [];
$array2 = array();  
foreach ($array1 as $index => $value) {
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);  
    if (isset($matches[1])) {
        $array2[$index] = str_replace($matches[0], "", $value); 
    } else {
        $array2[$index] = $value;  
    }
}
print_r($array2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! That worked fine for me, although the other suggestions also worked as well. I decided to use your version because its most handy for my code. That's also why I selected it as accepted answer.

Comment: Code-only answers represent the lowest value to Stack Overflow; please always include a plain English explanation of how your code works and why you feel it is the most appropriate resolution for the task.

Comment: @mickmackusa will keep in mind for the next time

Comment: @bear87 I fail to see why this unexplained and [provably incorrect answer](https://3v4l.org/uDD53) has been chosen as the best answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex on each element.

This will find an open parenthesis. followed by any characters until a closed parenthesis. When found, the first match will be returned else a `&nbsp;`.

```
print_r(array_map(
    fn($item) => preg_match('/(\(.*?\))/', $item, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '&nbsp;', 
    ['foo (bar1)', 'bar (foo2)', 'bas', 'foo (bas3)', 'bar']
));
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => (bar1)
    [1] => (foo2)
    [2] => &nbsp;
    [3] => (bas3)
    [4] => &nbsp;
)
```

Comment: When "capturing" the fullstring match, [the capture group can be removed and the fullstring match used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75646186/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

A variant using `array_walk()`:

```
<?php
$input = [
  0 => "foo (bar1)",
  1 => "bar (foo2)",
  2 => "bas",
  3 => "foo (bas3)",
  4 => "bar",
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry, $key) use (&$output) {
  $output[$key] = preg_match('|\([^\)]*\)|', $entry, $token) ? $token[0] : "&nbsp;";
});

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (bar1)
    [1] => (foo2)
    [2] => &nbsp;
    [3] => (bas3)
    [4] => &nbsp;
)
```

Comment: I noticed that you've been opting for `array_walk()` to populate globally scoped result variables in your recent answers.  It just seems like a more verbose version of `foreach()` in these cases.  Can you tell me why you prefer this approach?

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not prefer this approach. It is a variant, just as I wrote above. Real world tasks tend to be more complex than the simplified questions asked here, actually we insist on questioners to simplify their tasks when asking. Variants offer a choice to pick from in specific situations. Which means that even if one variant is not immediately "better" than another one the fact that variants exist is a value by itself.

Answer (score 0):

With foreach and a formatted string:

```
$arr = ['foo (bar1)', 'bar (foo2)', 'bas', 'foo (bas3)', 'bar'];
$res = [];

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    sscanf($v, '%[^ (] %s', $arr[$k], $res[$k]);
    $res[$k] = $res[$k] ?? ''; // or '&nbsp;'
}

print_r($arr);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: While the PHP documentation only recently mentioned it, [`sscanf()` has always been able to ignore unneeded matching substrings using `*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75646186/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

I think most simply, this task is a good candidate for iterated calls of `strstr()` (`strpbrk()` has the same functionality with a character mask).  If the sought opening parenthesis is not found, fallback to the `&nbsp;`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lk7FU))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => strstr($v, '(') ?: '&nbsp;', $array)
);
```

---

As a deviation from Casimir's `sscanf()` solution, I prefer to use `array_map()` and ignore the substring before the parentheses while parsing ([using `*`](https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/1571)).

Upon attempting to parse each string, the function will return a single-element array with either `null`, or the parenthetical value.  If `null` fallback to the desired `&nbsp;` string.

In the parsing pattern, `%*[^(]` means match but do not retain characters from the start of the string to the first occurring opening parenthesis. Then the `%s` will match and retain all subsequent non-whitespace characters.  That retained parenthetical substring can be accessed as the first element in `sscanf()`'s returned array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BJE1u))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => sscanf($v, '%*[^(]%s')[0] ?? '&nbsp;', $array)
);
```

---

The regex version of this is: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GOqCg))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => preg_replace('/[^(]*(.*)/', '$1', $v) ?: '&nbsp;', $array)
);
```

Or with `preg_match()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MXuUB))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => preg_match('/\(.+\)/', $v, $m) ? $m[0] : '&nbsp;', $array)
);
```